# Como mensurar a quantidade de espaço necessária em disco para uma operação ALTER TABLE?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, postgresql

Preciso fazer algumas alterações em uma das tabelas para adicionar novas colunas. O problema é que não consigo de forma alguma. Recebo o seguinte erro:

> PG::DiskFull: ERROR:  could not extend file "base/1672994/5557167.4":
>   No space left on device. HINT:  Check free disk space.

Bem, não há dúvida de que preciso aumentar o meu espaço em disco, já que nem mesmo uma operação `VACUUM FULL` deu certo, apresentando esse mesmo problema.

A *query* que tentei fazer é a seguinte:

`ALTER TABLE messages ADD COLUMN readed BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE;`

É um campo simples, e boolean não ocupa muito espaço. Mas lendo em outros fóruns, vi algo relacionado ao fato de que o PG precisa de mais espaço para fazer uma operação assim. Não sei ao certo como funciona, mas essa tabela que tento alterar tem mais de 6.700.000 linhas, e levando isso em consideração, talvez faça sentido o fato de o espaço atual não ser o suficiente para a operação.

Mas enfim. O que quero saber é: Existe uma forma de eu calcular em média quanto espaço adicional vou precisar comprar para que essa operação funcione? E como funciona essa questão do `ALTER TABLE`? Realmente precisa de muito mais espaço pra funcionar?

Comment: Eu entendo que como o PostgreSQL utiliza MVCC (Multiversion Concurrency Control) ele irá gerar uma cópia de toda a tabela, acrescentando nela o novo campo, e apenas ao final remover a tabela antiga. Talvez um pg_dumpall (em outro meio de armazenamento), modificar a definição da tabela no arquivo gerado, apagar o banco e recria-lo dom o psql possa ser uma solução.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É difícil dar uma resposta definitiva sobre isso e a tentativa e erro acaba sendo um método eficaz para descobrir até onde ir.

De fato é um pouco estranho precisar de tanto espaço porque a forma como está fazendo não deveria alterar toda a tabela. O PostgreSQL tem um mecanismo em que ele vai alterando as linhas conforme tem escrita nela. Enquanto não tem escrita, ela pega a linha sem a coluna e considera o valor *default* para a *query* de leitura. É bem inteligente. Mas por alguma razão isso parece não estar funcionando.

A ideia básica é ver o tamanho da tabela. Para listar as tabelas:

```
SELECT pg_database.datname, pg_database_size(pg_database.datname),
    pg_size_pretty(pg_database_size(pg_database.datname))
FROM pg_database ORDER BY pg_database_size DESC
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Select/CalcSpaceNeededToQuery.sql).

Pode ser que isso não seja suficiente já que pode haver alterações no índice também ou precisar de outras manipulações que só analisando o funcionamento interno do PostgreSQL para ter certeza.

Comment: Você mencionou que pode haver alterações no índice...
Nessa tabela em questão, há 15 índices. Eles são sobre campos INT, DATE, e TIMESTAMP. Todos eles são bTree. Isso influencia?

Comment: Eu acho até que não vai alterar, porque só faz sentido alterar o índice primário, que deve ser *clusterizado*, ou seja, é a própria tabela. Eu só coloquei porque pode ser que tenha algo que eu não sei e você tem a informação que pode ser mais que o tamanho da tabela. Tem que testar. Comece liberando o tamanho da tabela. Embora como eu disse, é estranho que precisa até isto.